# error renderIntoDocument is not a function with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

**Problem:**

I am testing React.Portal with react-testing-library, I find { renderIntoDocument } from react-testing-library but not found (in the documentation)

**Version:**

"@testing-library/dom": "^6.1.0"

"@testing-library/react": "9.1.3"

**Code example:**

```
import { cleanup, renderIntoDocument } from '@testing-library/react';
import { bindElementToQueries } from '@testing-library/dom';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

const bodyUtils = bindElementToQueries(document.body);

function renderMyPortal() {
    beforeEach(cleanup);
    const renderUtils = renderIntoDocument(
      <Module {...defaultProps} />,
    );
    const portalNode = bodyUtils.getByTestId('form');
    return {
      portalNode,
      ...renderUtils,
      ...bindElementToQueries(portalNode),
  };
}

it('renders', () => {
    const { container } = renderMyPortal(<Module {...defaultProps} />);

    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**TypeError:** (0 , _react2.renderIntoDocument) is not a function

Comment: `renderIntoDocument` [has gone in v. 4.0.0](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v4.0.0).